# Como faço pra não exibir a lista de diretórios?

Tags: php, apache

Olá, então minha dúvida é o seguinte, eu tenho uma pasta chamada **admin** e outra chamada **geral**, que fica dentro da **admin**. Dentro da pasta admin eu tenho um arquivo chamado geral.php até ai tudo bem, o problema é que se eu acessar assim:

http://localhost/forum/admin/geral/

ele entra na pasta geral e exibe tudo que tem nela, sendo que eu não quero exibir nada muito menos uma lista de diretorios teria como evitar isso? eu tentei com o htaccess e não obtive sucesso, agora se eu acessar assim ele abre o arquivo geral.php

http://localhost/forum/admin/geral.php

Tentei usar o htacess como tinha dito dessa forma:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^geral(.*)$ geral.php
RewriteRule ^teste(.*)$ teste.php
```

E ele continua entrando na pasta geral ao invés de entrar no arquivo geral.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione essa linha no começo do seu htaccess e pronto

```
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: Essa resposta foi muito útil, obrigado Leo!

Answer (score 1):

Modo SuperRápido para resolver este problema

> crie um arquivo "index.html" em branco e coloque na pasta 'geral' (metodologia JOOMLA)

Você pode resolver o problema com o index.html em branco ou através de configuração no apache na pasta admin, [conforme o site](http://wbruno.com.br/php/desmistificando-urls-amigaveis-com-php-e-htaccessapache/).

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/$ $1.php [NC]
```

Esta regra deve fazer o seguinte, ao acessar a URL "amigável" será redirecionado para o '.php'.

Ou seja o cliente acessa a URL '/geral/' o servidor roda o arquivo 'geral.php'

> http://localhost/admin/geral/ -> http://localhost/admin/geral.php
>
> http://localhost/admin/pipoca/ -> http://localhost/admin/pipoca.php

Alias recomendo a resposta do Leo Letto e colocar também:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: É um pouco inviável ficar criando um index.html em cada pasta, não acha que seria mais fácil usar htaccess?

Comment: Tem razão estou pesquisando e vou editar minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo as seguintes leituras:

[Bloqueando lista de diretorios do Apache](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Bloqueando-lista-de-diretorios-do-Apache) 
aqui é preciso editar o arquivo httpd.conf ou apache.conf e editar o código para que ele fique parecido com o seguinte:

```
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
    Options +indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

e

[Impedindo listagem de arquivos e diretórios com o .htaccess (Apache)](http://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/impedindo-listagem-de-arquivos-e-diretorios-com-o-htaccess-apache/)

nesse caso você pode optar por colocar o seguinte código no .htaccess

```
## Impedindo a listagem de qualquer arquivo e diretório
Options -Indexes
```

ou indo um pouco além e impedindo que somente algumas extensões seja bloqueada da listagem
exemplo:

```
## Impedindo a listagem do próprio de arquivos .jpg e png
IndexIgnore .jpg, .png
```